# When building an application using package.json, how can I select different dependency versions for development?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a Javascript package (*A*) which uses one of our own packages (*B*) as a dependency. Neither is on the NPM registry. *A* is an application, and *B* is installed directly from github using specifiers like this: `github:user/project#version`

When *A* is built with `npm install; npm run build` we normally want it to use the version of *B* defined in `package.json`'s dependencies. So set the production version here, say: `github:user/B#semver:^1.0.0`. All good.

What I would like is to be able to build a development version of *A* with everything the same but with the development branch of *B*: `github:user/B#dev`.

`devDependencies` does not seem to be designed for this, rather for dependencies which are entirely absent in production. `NODE_ENV` environment variable doesn't seem able to affect the behaviour of `install`.

Currently I edit *A*'s `package.json` dependencies to use `github:user/B#dev`, and remember not to commit this to the `master` branch. And if do I commit it to the `dev` branch, then I can't simply have `dev` follow `master` in a fast-forwarding manner, instead I have to maintain two branches and merge `dev` across to `master`.

```
----+---+---+---> dev
     \   \   \
      v   v   v
------+---+---+--> master
```

This is inconvenient and potentially error-prone.

I would guess that my situation is not an unusual one, and that there might be a better solution for this out there.

How do other people solve this?

Comment: Just so I understand, you have 2 branches, and the versions of the dependancies should be different on each branch?

Comment: I don't really want two branches, I want one, which can do two things (dev and prod)

Comment: ah I understand - you have a self-built package that you use in an application, and are looking for the best way to use the ‘dev’ package when in the ‘dev’ mode of the application? Otherwise both should be prod/master

Comment: @james yes, that's it

Answer (score 0):

After a few comments I now understand your requirement. The answer is, it depends on *how* you plan to differentiate a `dev` and `prod` version of your application.

**Different Deployments**

One option, is to have two separate deployments of your application - one for development, and one for production. If the source code itself should be the same, the rather than having two separate repos, you could use a **monorepo** with two different `package.json` inside, one for development purposes, and the other for production.

**Aliases**

The other option, would be to make use of the `npm alias` functionality - npm now supports package aliasing like the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "prodPackage": "npm:mypackage@prod",
  "devPackage": "npm:mypackage@dev"
}
```

If you then need to focus on how this is used in your code, the `NODE_ENV` variable could then be used to control this:

```
const Package = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod' ? require('prodPackage') : require('devPackage')
```

Or create a more specific env variable that defines your package, then change this in your environments to be which version you require, like so:

```
#in .env
MY_PACKAGE=devPackage #or prodPackage 

// in your .js files
const Package = require(`${process.env.MY_PACKAGE}`)
```

**Package.json & Source Control**

The only other alternative that springs to mind (which is much less preferred), is to either remove `package.json` from source control and use local ones depending on `dev` or `prod`.

There is no official approach to this unfortunately, but there are ways to manage it - including the one you mentioned above. You can decide which one best suits you if any.

Either way, using the alias approach or different deployments, you wont have to worry about keeping separate branches. I hope any of this helps.

Comment: Re. different deployments: we have multiple apps (A, C D, E etc.) depending on a library (B). I'm not certain a monorepo helps for that, as it seems to need checking B into each repository for A, C, D, E etc.?

Comment: Re. aliases: this entails adding B#1.0 and B#dev both as dependencies of A, and then choosing at runtime. Might work to allow switching on a parameter in NODE_ENV? But it seems overkill to add this extra code and logic into the production version too.

Comment: Re. package.json & source control: this seems equivalent to what I was trying to avoid, with a package.json which differs between development and production branches.

Comment: @wu-lee a monorepo would involve putting all your applications (A,B,C,D etc.) into one repo - which is now I realise you have so many apps, this is potentially not possible for you

Comment: So all in all, I'm still scratching my head and feeling that there isn't yet any very nice solution in view. Perhaps another way might be: a run-script `build-dev` which sets the dependency to #dev temporarily, builds, then reverts package.json?

Comment: @wu-lee I agree the alias option seems overkill, but it will eradicate your branch problem - the other options would be to provide your own install script in the package.json.... this would be responsible for installing your dependencies depending on the branch you are on. If this sounds like a feasible option for you I will edit my answer of how to do that?

Comment: some sort of dev-mode install seems most appealing so far. Would be nice if it didn't require editing and then reverting package.json